# What has higher performance used within large loops: .indexOf(str) or .match(regex)?

Tags: javascript, regex, arrays, match, indexof

I have this array.prototype on my page and it seems to be sucking up a lot of processing time:

```
        Array.prototype.findInArray = function(searchStr) {
          var returnArray = false;
          for (i=0; i<this.length; i++) {
            if (typeof(searchStr) == 'function') {
              if (searchStr.test(this[i])) {
                if (!returnArray) { returnArray = [] }
                returnArray.push(i);
              }
            } else {
              var regexp = new RegExp(".*" + searchStr + ".*");
              if (this[i].match(regexp)) {
                if (!returnArray) { returnArray = [] }
                returnArray.push(i);
              }
            }
          }
          return returnArray;
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you time it both ways? I suspect that indexOf will be faster in most cases, but it's better to test than to suspect.

Comment: Don't forget that every environment can be different. Time it in Firefox and you may bet a different outcome than in Opera, Chrome, or Safari. I'd time it in Internet Explorer since it's the runt of the pack--get it fast in IE and it should be plenty fast everywhere else.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, you know that you don't have to have the ".*" on either side, right? A regular expression already by default will match anywhere inside the string. Second, if you are just searching for a constant string, and don't need to use any of the advanced stuff that regular expressions offer, then it's definitely faster to use `.indexOf()`. Plus that way you won't have to worry about escaping characters that have special meaning.

Comment: +1  I cannot imagine how a regular expression could beat indexOf. If you don't need regex-power, don't use regex.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions can vary wildly.  I imagine that a simple, well-crafted regular expression might work as fast or faster than indexOf().  On the other hand, a complex regular expression would need more time since it's doing more work.

You also have a browser implementation issue clouding matters.  Short of writing a timed loop to measure the time taken for each browser to do each type of detection with your specific needs, you can't really get a solid answer.

Answer (score 0):

What is worse is you create a new regular expression object on every iteration of the loop-
define it once, outside the loop, or pass it as an argument.

Also, for this use, **test** is better and quicker than **match**.